# prevent horizontal scroll on blur for input

Tags: css, input, horizontal-scrolling, onblur

I am using an input and truncating the text with`text-overflow: ellipsis` but when one scrolls horizontally on the input when it is not focused, you can scroll past the ellipsis and see white space/blank input space. Is there a way to prevent that horizontal scroll from happening? Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Here is the input code:

```js
<InputWrapper>
   <Form.Input
      label='Text - 30 Char Limit'
      maxLength='30'
      placeholder='this input accepts up to 30 characters'
   />
</InputWrapper>
```

and the styled component css:

```js
const InputWrapper = styled.span`
.ui.input input {
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  }
`;
```

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden`

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: will need code to help you

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO edited the initial post with code.

Comment: let me check it

Comment: not a browser thing, just tried it on a trackpad and it really isnt working as should

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure why it does it or how to resolve it.

Comment: There might be one way with js, but i would be more about saving the content in a var and just leave enough so the eclipse works